# Image cache is not generated properly when importing new products - Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-upload, media-images, gallery-image

I have recently imported 200 products, the import went well and the images do show up on the back-end correctly, however there is no cached version available. If I look at the category page and image that supposed to show up is expected to be in the following location:

```
cache/9b5a790ce75ed6826aa4463bc16b3bc1/a/v/avant-d15-vision-of-love.jpg
```

When I do a search there are multiple images with the same name showing up in the cache directory but elsewhere:

```
find . -name avant-d15-vision-of-love.jpg
./cache/1677d012f6d3f9a624d33d91ea04b887/a/v/avant-d15-vision-of-love.jpg
./cache/8345bde2c7027c4e6418fcda55997597/a/v/avant-d15-vision-of-love.jpg
./cache/5db09c8cfd726a46996de64dc6365508/a/v/avant-d15-vision-of-love.jpg
./cache/b1799097c85e4d88dfbcc551a1d969fc/a/v/avant-d15-vision-of-love.jpg
./cache/cd831224a3bfc78b7eea938937e3e8e6/a/v/avant-d15-vision-of-love.jpg
./cache/76cf6d416a4967076c5ca34aaeae4b62/a/v/avant-d15-vision-of-love.jpg
```

My question is where are these image link stored in the database? Could it be that the images have been generated in the wrong directory?

Also please don't tell me to do a **magento catalog:images:resize** as I have 15K products and it runs for 3 days. I can't simply do this everytime I upload new products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was permissions. There weren't sufficient permissions on the ./var/resource_config.json file. Once the permissions has been changed all images were generated automatically upon page load.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable [product flat tabl](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-flat.html)e then you have doing indexing.

Also, you must have to  run `bin/magento catalog:images:resize`

Comment: I have done the indexing multiple times already today, also I asked for a solution that does NOT involve the running of the bin/magento catalog:images:resize command as I have 15K products and it runs for 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

in your etc/view.xml of your theme change the value of this

```
<var name="product_image_white_borders">0</var>
```

and flush the cache ; work for me